# List of EU countries from webservice

Tags: web-services

I need to know if a country belongs to the European Union.
I could create a list of nations that belong to the union **now**, but if they change I should update all the programs because the list is static.
I would like to find a webservice that gives me this data starting (for example) by the ISO code.
But I am not able to find any similar service.
Does anyone know if there is already this service?

Thanks to everyone.

*Note: i'm looking for a list of EU countries, not a list of all the countries in the European continent.*

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find it on the EU website; maybe start from [this page](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/services/interactive_services/index_en.htm). F.ex. I know for sure they offer a free webservice to check if a VAT number exists. You might get lucky also by asking on their forum (find it in that same page).